# How to parse json file in hadoop?

Tags: json, parsing, hadoop

I have the following JSON file in hadoop.

```
{
  "reviewerID": "ABC1234",
  "productID": "ABCDEF",
  "reviewText": "GOOD!",
  "rating": 5.0,
},
{
  "reviewerID": "ABC5678",
  "productID": "GFMKDS",
  "reviewText": "Not bad!",
  "rating": 3.0,
}
```

The result of parse that i want is textfile.

```
ABC1234::ABCDEF::5.0
ABC5678::GFMKDS::3.0
```

How to parse json file in hadoop?

Comment: What have you tried till now? Yes the parsing is absolutely possible but with which tool would you like to parse the JSON?

Comment: I will use java.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java)